# Uber API - Pay for other user ride. Possible?

Tags: uber-api

We are developing an application where we need to pay for different users rides from our own credit card. Kinda Uber Business but without manual adding of accounts. Is it possible with Uber API?

Comment: Have you asked Uber support?  I asked a similar question, poked them a couple times, and still never heard back

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, paying for other users' rides is not possible in the Uber API today.